# Why does this same question keep getting "bumped to the homepage"?

Tags: bug, community-user, bump

I've noticed in a particular topic a single question from 2011 has been "bumped to the homepage" several times. According to the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4888734/revisions), 14 times. I'm trying to understand why.

[This thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579) suggests a few possible factors: views and edits. There were answers/edits added in 2013, 2014 and 2017, but most were on the same day. So while that might have prompted a few bumps, not 14. If I'm using the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/839271/1035603/) correctly, the question does have a lot of views, which could partially explain it. However, not why this *same* question keeps getting bumped and not others with similar tags and a lot of views over time.

My questions are:

1. Why does this *specific* question keep getting bumped to the homepage? IMHO there are other unanswered questions, with similar tags, that would benefit from it more than this one.
2. What, if anything, can be done to stop it from being "bumped to the home page"again? (On the surface, it's a valid question, and doesn't seem to qualify for being closed as "off-topic" etc.... Despite being bumped repeatedly, it hasn't attracted much new activity. For those familiar with the language, it's a common issue with very specific solutions that were already posted. So it's unlikely to attract further answers or spark additional discussion. Given that the question has remained open since the author's last visit in 2011, seems unlikely they'll be back to close it.)

**(Note, tagged as "bug" only because the interface warned "At least one of these tags is required ..." and bug seemed the best fit)**

Comment: The algorithm that does this lost its marbles.  It used to pick random posts but got self-aware somehow.  We can't get them to fix it.  The only workaround I found it to stop it by upvoting an answer.  Somebody did on Stefano's post, so that should be fixed now for this one.

Comment: @yivi - Thanks. Ugh... guess my search phrase was off because I couldn't find a duplicate thread when searching last night...

Comment: @HansPassant - Hm... the thread yivi linked suggests a downvote on the question would stop it - but it didn't. The question was bumped again yesterday. Will have to read the rest of the thread to see if it explains why...

Comment: @Ageax It's because other people upvoted it, resulting in it having a positive score.

Comment: DVs on the question works too, but it is usually much harder because they tend to have too many UVs from being exposed so often.  Can't be done by just one person.  It is not like I really want to advocate upvoting a crappy answer, but sometimes desperate measures are appropriate.  9000+ views on this one, ouch.

Comment: @Servy - As you can see, there's not much voting on the entire thread. I'm not sure how recently those votes were, except for mine trying to get it to stop being bumped....

Comment: @Ageax I was merely answering your question of why downvoting it didn't stop it from being bumped.  It's because there were enough upvotes for the score to be positive.

Comment: @HansPassant - Exactly. I tried to upvote the best answer yesterday in the hopes that it would stop appearing.  It's actually a common beginner question in the language, with simple well known solutions (that haven't changed in umpteen years). That probably explains why there's so little activity. I'm just tired of seeing that same question over and over.. and not others in the topic that could use more attention...  ;-)

Comment: @Servy - Sorry, didn't see the edit in time! :)  Appreciate the answer.

Comment: "The algorithm that does this lost its marbles."  Seems like that about sums it up...